# How to position Tooltip arrow according to anchroview in android.

Tags: android

[image]

I am using Popup Window to derive the tool tip but facing some issue to dynamically place the arrow head according to the position of the anchor view on screen.

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: Please Refer to the diagram and comment below

Answer (score 0):

One thing what you can do is find the location of the anchored view on the screen and set the x,y coordinate of your pop up layout accordingly. To find the real world coordinates, you can use the following code:

```
    public static Rect locateView(View v) {
    int[] loc_int = new int[2];
    v.getLocationOnScreen(loc_int);

    Rect location = new Rect();
    location.left = loc_int[0];
    location.top = loc_int[1];
    location.right = location.left + v.getWidth();
    location.bottom = location.top + v.getHeight() + v.getPaddingTop() + v.getBottom();
    return location;
}
```

Pass your anchored view to the function, and later on, you setX,SetY property of your popup.
Something like:

```
 popUpLayout.setX(locateView(findViewById(R.id.anchor_view)).left);
```

Second solution, may be you can just put wrap your anchored view and pop up in a linear/relative layout and play with visibility.

Comment: How to place a triangle in the layout? My problem is regarding how to attach the triangle on top of the popup window( may be bottom of the popup window in case I want to show the popup above the anchor view). Position of triangle must always be within the left and right boundary of the anhorview. So depending on the width of the tooltip and available screen width I need to place a triangle. So  I stuck with following 2 questions
1. How to add a triangle to the layout . Considering I am using PopupWindow class in android and inflating a LinearLayout as content of the PopupWindow

Comment: Any update on this?